# Was Einsteins work with relativity necessary for successful space travel?

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, rocket-science, space-travel, solar-system-exploration

So I know that Einstein and general relativity had huge impacts on the way we view the world, but how crucial were these scientific advancements to the success of our space programs? Would Newtonian physics sufficed, or would using those formulas and methodologies when travelling off-Earth and to the Moon resulted in catastrophic failures?

Comment: [This blog article](http://backreaction.blogspot.co.uk/2008/01/messenger-mercury-and-general.html) looks relevant, though the pictures are broken at the moment.

Comment: Surely there is a valid physics answer here: simple calculations of paths in inverse square field and compare the path with a geodesic in the Schwarzschild metric? So to and from the moon, no, there is no practical difference: if you want to know the position of a space station orbiting at Mercury's distance from the Sun and you're using this space station as a positioning system beacon, then yes absolutely you'll need to use the GR calculations. It all depends on your application, but your question is a good one, so I don't agree with the close votes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, relativistic effects are accounted for in all space travel.  These effects were apparently minor enough during the Apollo missions to rely on standard Newtonian equations and minor course corrections enroute, but are pronounced enough on longer missions within the solar system to account for several kilometer errors.

> General relativity is routinely accounted for in  spacecraft
>   navigation.... the NASA navigation software developed  at
>   JPL....incorporates the Ted Moyer formulations for navigation, which
>   includes mathematical expressions that describe the effects  of
>   general relativity.

**References**
[RELATIVISTIC TIME CORRECTIONS
FOR APOLLO 12 AND APOLLO 13](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19720022040.pdf)
[Accounting for General Relativity at Mercury](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2008/1329.html)

Comment: That's actually the opposite of what I've heard. Do you have sources?

Comment: I'm looking for some.

Comment: Here we go: http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19720022040.pdf

Comment: Not to be a pain, but that file seems to be analyzing how a clock carried on the spacecraft would differ from one kept on Earth. It doesn't say anything about the trajectory of the spacecraft, as far as I can tell, which it would need to in order to be relevant to this question.

Comment: @DavidZ: Time and navigation are inextricably intertwined.  Without an accurate timepiece, accurate navigation is impossible.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've heard from several professors that Newtonian mechanics was used for the calculations involved in the Moon missions. Are you absolutely sure?

Comment: That doesn't automatically mean relativistic corrections need to be taken into account to navigate to the moon and back. The PDF file shows an accumulated advance of 570 _microseconds_; are you saying that an inaccuracy in the clock of less than a millisecond is enough to make the Apollo craft miss the moon by several miles? I'd like to see that specific claim backed up more fully. (The blog post does show that relativity is necessary for at least _some_ spacecraft operations, so the overall answer is clearly "yes", but it doesn't address the Apollo missions specifically.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Also, the date on that report shows that this was a calculation carried out AFTER the first mission to the Moon (1969), for missions AFTER those that first had people stand on the Moon's surface (Apollo 11). The calculations are also for a mission that was already over.

Comment: I know we account for it a lot now, and especially for longer missions, but I suppose I'm most interested in manned missions, especially moon missions. I was wondering if the scale of the moon missions was enough to necessitate compensation for relativity. I was also wondering if we had not had the knowledge of the universe from Einstein when we went to do space travel if we would have learned the hard way that our Newtonian calculations we wrong.

Comment: @DLeh: Relativistic effects aren't the only problem.  [See here](http://www.universetoday.com/91254/how-will-msl-navigate-to-mars-very-precisely/) and [here](http://relativity.livingreviews.org/open?pubNo=lrr-2010-4&amp;page=articlesu12.html) to get a feel for how complex the problem of space navigation can be.  While relativistic effects may not have been considered when formulating the initial calculations, small course corrections to account  for relativistic effects were almost certainly required.

Comment: Oh i realize it's very complicated. (I've played kerbel space program :P) I'm just curious how much weight (heh) the difference between Newtonian and Einsteinian physics really has on these relatively small scale journeys.

Comment: It would have been a relatively small effect for moon missions, given the ability to navigate and apply small course corrections.